# WPF DataGrid - Add Items if Button was clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid

This is my code:
But I will Add the values (see code) if someone clicked the Button "Einfügen".

But it doesn't work, It only change his values!

Thanks for all helpers!

```
        private void Einfügen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsEnd = new List<Plan>();
        itemsEnd.Add(new Plan(LinieZ, Convert.ToString(Kurs.SelectedItem), AbfZ, VonZ, NachZ, AnkZ, "---"));
        Plan.ItemsSource = itemsEnd;
    }

    class Plan
{
    public string Linie { get; set; }
    public string Kurs { get; set; }
    public string Abfahrt { get; set; }
    public string Von { get; set; }
    public string Nach { get; set; }
    public string Ankunft { get; set; }
    public string Pause { get; set; }

    public Plan(string Linie, string Kurs, string Abfahrt, string Von, string Nach, string Ankunft, string Pause)
    {
        this.Linie = Linie;
        this.Kurs = Kurs;
        this.Abfahrt = Abfahrt;
        this.Von = Von;
        this.Nach = Nach;
        this.Ankunft = Ankunft;
        this.Pause = Pause;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are `resetting` the `ItemsSource` each time to a brand new `List` (of size 1). You are not appending to the `List`, but instead, you are creating a `List` that only has the new item, then setting that `List` to the `DataGrid`.

You can have a predefined list that you add to.

Something like:

```
private ObservableCollection<Plan> _items = new ObservableCollection<Plan>();

public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Plan.ItemsSource = _items;
}

private void Einfügen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _items.Add(new Plan(LinieZ, Convert.ToString(Kurs.SelectedItem), AbfZ, VonZ, NachZ, AnkZ, "---"));
}
```

Though, I would suggest not going this route. Look into `MVVM`, `DataBinding`, and `Commands`. Ideally, you would want to create a `ViewModel` that contains an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `DataGrid`. Inside that `ViewModel` will be a command that will add items to that `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: The code doesn't work because "The best correspondence for the florid system. Collections. Generic. Cunning. Add (plan) method has some invalid arguments." I thank that is because of the var item and that itemsEnd need more strings...

Comment: @Nick_SMI awesome, glad I could help. make sure you accept the answer by clicking the check mark. =]

Comment: would you mind if you tell me how I can make a "foreach" with the rows of my DataGrid and this _items?

Comment: @Nick_SMI not sure if I understand your question. a foreach for what? if you post a separate question with an example of what you are trying to do, i can try and help

Comment: I want a loop, that do something foreach row in my DataGrid Row, do you understand. If you don't, I can post a separte question ;) @d.moncada

Comment: I opended an new topic! :D